# Plotting two convex hulls in R

Tags: r

I have computed two complex hulls in R (using convhulln in geometry package)

```
tt7
dd7
```

When I plot them, though:

```
 plot(dd7, main="Convex hull for benchmark 7 with delay", xlab="Ticks per fault", ylab="Total Faults", xlim=c(550,1300), ylim=c(1650, 2400))
 plot(tt7, add=TRUE, col="red")
```

I only get the outline of the second one - how do I get the points as well?

[image]

Cannot find any documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `chull` from base R for polygons because `convhulln` gives triangles. If you insist on using `convhulln`, you'll have to [sort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48250095/7128934) the indices of points first. Use `plot` at the beginning and then use `polygon` or `points`

```
#DATA
set.seed(42)
m1 = matrix(rnorm(40), ncol = 2)
m2 = 3 + matrix(rnorm(40), ncol = 2)

ch1 = chull(m1)
ch2 = chull(m2)

#Create empty plot with all points
plot(rbind(m1, m2), type = "n")

#First set of Data
points(m1)
polygon(m1[ch1,])

#Second set of Data
points(m2, col = "red")
polygon(m2[ch2,], border = "red")
```

[image]